# Assignment alternation: OR when assigning values

Tags: r

I have several variables (from parsing text) which may or may not be empty strings. I would like to try to use the first true value of several alternate variables to a new canonical variable. Something like:

```
canon = foo || bar || quux || NA
```

And if `foo=""`, `bar="Barney"`, `quux="Wilma"` then `canon="Barney"` but if `bar` were empty, `canon="Wilma"` etc. I currently get the following error:

```
Error in foo || bar : invalid 'x' type in 'x || y'
```

Searching for the error turns up nothing helpful, nor have I found much when looking for examples of logical assignments in R. How can one accomplish this in R?

Comment: The error is because you use "character"s with `||` ("Barney" || "Wilma"). Depending on your actual problem, you could concatenate "foo", "bar" etc in a "vector" and use `canon = x[nzchar(x)][1]` -- `x = c("", "Barney", "Wilma"); x[nzchar(x)][1]`, `x = c("", "", ""); x[nzchar(x)][1]`

Comment: Googling for implementations of the SQL function `coalesce` in R might be instructive, although I agree with alexis that if you've organized your code around multiple individual variables with only a single value, that will probably be the biggest barrier as it isn't very R-like.

Comment: The variables are a simplification. I'm actually using a mixture of variables and expressions which are extract-ed/ing from different pieces of text. R-like or no, this is the most straight-forward way to structure things. The SQL coalesce analogy is interesting though, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that `||` is just for checking values, and works differently than you might expect from other languages.

If you can include all of your values in a matrix/data.frame, you can use something like this:

```
set.seed(12345)
df <-
  data.frame(
    foo = sample(c("",LETTERS),100
                 , TRUE, prob = c(1,rep(1/52,26)))
    , bar = sample(c("",letters),100
                   , TRUE, prob = c(1,rep(1/52,26)))
    , quux = sample(c("",1:26),100
                    , TRUE, prob = c(1,rep(1/52,26)))
  )

# head(df)

canon <-
  apply(df,1,function(x){
    # Find the real values
    realValues <- which(x != "")

    ifelse(length(realValues) > 0 # Check if any real values exist
           , x[realValues[1]] # if so, return the first one
           , NA) # If not, return NA
  })
```

How much simpler do you want it? This is not a native request, but the code was still only 3 functions (`apply`, `which`, and `ifelse`). Would you prefer it wrapped in a function that allows you to not have to make the data.frame? That is probably worthwhile if this is something you use commonly.

```
makeCanon <- function(x, ...){
  if(class(x) %in% c("data.frame","matrix")){
    df <- x
  } else{
    df <- as.data.frame(list(x, ...))
  }

  out <-
    apply(df,1,function(z){
      realValues <- which(z != "")
      ifelse(length(realValues) > 0
             , z[realValues[1]]
             , NA)
    })
  return(out)

}

fromDF <- makeCanon(df)

fromVectors <- makeCanon(df$foo, df$bar, df$quux)

table(fromDF == fromVectors)
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like it should be something that could be accomplished much more simply, but then that seems to be the case for so many things in R :-P  I've also found it easier to simlpy do `canon(list(...))`

Comment: A word of warning for others, this does not handle NULL values as one would expect i.e; they are passed through as true values. `realValues <- which(x != "" & !is.null(x))` should seemingly fix this but does not, although the equivalent to reject NA does.

Answer (score 1):

While a vectorized option is probably best, if you want to keep your original syntax for readability (?) you can implement a variation of `||`:

```
"%||%" <- function(x, y) if (x == '') y else x

foo  = ""
bar  = "Barney"
quux = "Wilma"

canon = foo %||% bar %||% quux %||% NA
```

I've seen this strategy for replacing `NULL` arguments with a default value (source: [dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/8b28b0b879419e5e14c033ac1fddea3bfa6065f4/R/utils.r#L94)). Note that this particular implementation will fail on `NA` and `NULL` and will give warnings if `foo`, `bar` or `quux` have multiple values (enter `is.na`, `is.null`, and `assertthat::is.string` for checking inputs).

Of course, `dplyr::coalesce` and `dplyr::na_if` looks even better to my eye:

```
library(dplyr)

# Convert troublesome values to NA
foo  = ""       %>% na_if("")
bar  = "Barney" %>% na_if("")
quux = "Wilma"  %>% na_if("")

# Vectorized so foo, bar, etc. should be the same length or length of 1
canon = coalesce(foo, bar, quux)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version based on Mark's solution that skips over NULL, NA, and empty strings.

```
library("gtools")
#Returns first real value, otherwise NA
canon = function(inputVector){
  realValues = Filter(Negate(invalid), inputVector)
  ifelse( length(realValues)>0, realValues[1], NA )
}
```